# Unable to run multiple AJAX calls without refreshing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form that contains a text field and a button. When I start typing, it shows hints from my database and upon clicking the button or hitting the enter key it displays search results. AJAX is used for both hints and search results, and it is working well.

The problem is that it only works the first time after the page loads. If I want another search, it doesn't respond. It just shows the previous search results until the page is refreshed, but the `showhint()` function works well.

```
<input type="text" id="txt"  onkeyup="showhint(this.value)"/>
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="searchresult()"/>
```

The AJAX function:

```
function searchresult() {
    var key = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("mid").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","keyprocess.php?q=" + key, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: i dnt knw who is moderator, i'll open 1000 times till i wont get solution.if u can, give solution never waste ur time on useless comment

Answer (score 5):

I'm **guessing** the reason it works the first time or on refresh is because the event handler is not persisting between ajax requests.  I would look into jQuery as it will help mitigate issues like this.

For jquery < version 1.7
The [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method does the following

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Anything after 1.7 you should use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Basically if the elements on the page change from an ajax request the .delegate() or .on() methods will still allow events to be handled.

Update:

```
//This needs to be within the $(document).ready function
//Attach an event handler to the ID called txt that fires on changes
$("body").on("change", "#txt", function(event){
    //get the value from the input
    var $val = $(this).val();

    //Send the $val to keyprocess.php via ajax call

    //Output Results

});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it is working for you now, cowboy.  Please mark as the accepted answer if it helped.